# What does "if nowhere else" mean here?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

"When I write a novel in which the central action is a baptism, I am very well aware that for a majority of my readers, baptism is a meaningless rite, and so in my novel I have to see that this baptism carries enough awe and mystery to jar the reader into some kind of emotional recognition of its significance.To this end I have to bend the whole novel—its language, its structure, its action.I have to make the reader feel in his bones **if nowhere else**, that something is going on that counts.Distortion in this case is an instrument; exaggeration has a purpose, and the whole structure of the story or novel is made what it is because of belief.This is not the kind of distortion that destroys;it is the kind that reveals, or should reveal."
                                   ————Flannery O’Connor

Does it mean at least?But "in his bones" has been an very high degree so I don’t think it makes sense.

Comment: You might feel it in your bones, your gut, or, as a last desperate act, your brain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"At least" is a close paraphrase. The phrase is a shortened version of the whole. "If" is a conjunction: *I have to make the reader feel in his bones if nowhere else that...* = *I have to make the reader feel in his bones **even** if **the reader feels it** nowhere else that...*

Comment: If "at least" is a close paraphrase then what is the difference between them?

Comment: **At least** indicates the barest minimum, it is often used in a half-pleading/half apologetic sense and may not indicate a full solution or satisfactory result. **If nowhere/nothing else** is more positive: it accepts the suggestion as a solution that has some merit.